# Scroll div inside hidden overflow div

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Is possible to achieve design I wanted below?

With conditions:-
- container `position:absolute` to stick it to bottom of page
- container `max-height:50%`
- body div is scroll-able without fixed height while page is not scroll-able

I want to toggle body div visibility by clicking in header so header div will stick to the bottom of page.

[image: tes]

What I've tried:-

```
.container {
    max-height: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
        // this makes .body div not scrollable
        // when this set to auto, header div will also scrollable
}

.content-body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's fiddle I created:- https://jsfiddle.net/vwoz8rr5/1/
If this is not possible or there are a better approach, I would like to know.
I would like to provide necessary information if needed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a better jsFiddle to give you a demo with scrollable content. (though you have to add the max-height: 50% rule if you want to match your constraints properly, do you want me to create another fiddle with that ?)

Comment: Added another answer with a better Fiddle based on our discussion. Consider accepting this last answer instead of the first one.

Comment: @daformat okay. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now that I understand better what you want to achieve, here is a better jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jqnxjkr0/ `Better version based on your feedback`

In this version:

- .container has a max height that is set to 50% of the viewport height.
- .content-header can have a variable height (e.g. multiple lines).
- .content-body will take the rest of the available height.
- .content-body can be scrolled when its content is too tall to fit.

If this version works for you, you should accept this answer instead of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052264/1358317) for a better fiddle.

Seems like a good job for flexbox, here are a few jsFiddle to give you an example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/aw5qt19x/ `// Basic flexbox usage`
- https://jsfiddle.net/aw5qt19x/2/ `// Based on your constraints / layout`
- https://jsfiddle.net/aw5qt19x/4/ `// Working demo with js`

Finally here is a more thorough demo with scrollable content:
https://jsfiddle.net/aw5qt19x/5/ `// Final?`

Comment: thank you for your answer. i think there's a little misundersanding. What i wanted is the body part to be scrollable while in your fiddle, it's the upper part of the page. i think a little modification will make it work.

Comment: also i need container height to be 50%

Comment: I mean, I think the upper part need to be scrollable too right?

Comment: Also, do you need .container to be at max-height: 50% (which means that it can be smaller if the content isn't tall enough) or at 50%, no matter what?

Comment: Here is a version with the container set to 50% of the viewport height (vh) permanently, and everything should be scrollable as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/aw5qt19x/7/

Comment: no, i'll fill the upper part by map. And yes i need it to be 50% at max depending on the content because i don't want it cover the map. Here's what i'm currently working on: http://imgur.com/a/gAmwt.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aw5qt19x/6/ seems working great. i'll accept this answer. Would be better if you edit your answers, so people coming in the future won't be confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134895/discussion-between-mathieu-jouhet-and-aldo-ginting).